# Strange apple dns answers

Tags: dns, dns-spoofing

Could someone please explain to the results of a reverse DNS lookup I ran? `dig -x 17.178.96.59`

I was expecting apple.com but it also listed a whole load of PTR's. Many looked like phishing sites like icloudc.om and jtunes.com for instance. All have a very high TTL as well.

Comment: `icloudc.om` does not exists, but several other variations do.

Answer (score 2):

This simply means that all these domain names are associated with the IP `17.178.96.59`.

Several domain names can be associated with the same IP address. This is common with name-based implementation of [Shared web hosting service:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service)

> #### Name-based
>
> In name-based virtual hosting, also called shared IP hosting, **the
>   virtual hosts serve multiple host names on a single machine with a
>   single IP address.** This is possible because when a web browser
>   requests a resource from a web server using HTTP/1.1 it includes the
>   requested host name as part of the request. The server uses this
>   information to determine which web site to show the user.
>
> <sup>Source: [Name-based - Shared web hosting service (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service#Name-based)</sup>

<sup>(Emphasis is mine)</sup>

In your particular case, all these domain names seems to belong to Apple; it's not surprising as Apple have to reason to share that single IP with anyone else. As of today, it looks like they all redirect you to the Apple webpage, but they could have done it otherwise. You could have got different website with these domain names, even though they are associated with the same IP.

As [schroeder](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6253/schroeder) said, one reason to *register* several domain names that looks similar is to avoid phishing or brand abuse (e.g. [typosquatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting)). I would like to add that another reason can be to *correct* user mistakes (e.g. https://googl.com/ redirects me to https://google.com/).

Note that my last paragraph doesn't involve that these domain names are associated with the same IP. My example with `googl.com` and `googl.com` shows it. But it's possible.

PS: You mention the domain name `12diasdepresentesdeitunes.com.br`, I don't get it when I type your command, so I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, companies will register domain names that are similar to their actual domain names or products to make sure someone does *not* use them for phishing or brand abuse.

This can be confirmed by running a whois query. I see that jtunes.com is, in fact, registered by Apple.

http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/domain/jtunes.com

Comment: I thought that might be the case but  one of the PTR's is 12diasdepresentesdeitunes.com.br which shows as resolving to 165.160.13.20