# Why nslookup by ip does not give the same domain name?

Tags: dns, ip

I first ran this command: `nslookup www.certifiedhacker.com`
This was the output:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
www.certifiedhacker.com canonical name = certifiedhacker.com.
Name:   certifiedhacker.com
Address: 162.241.216.11
```

When I ran: `nslookup 162.241.216.11`
this was the output.

```
11.216.241.162.in-addr.arpa     name = box5331.bluehost.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
241.162.in-addr.arpa    nameserver = ns1.unifiedlayer.com.
241.162.in-addr.arpa    nameserver = ns2.unifiedlayer.com.
ns1.unifiedlayer.com    internet address = 162.159.24.11
ns2.unifiedlayer.com    internet address = 162.159.25.92
```

So in DNS lookup of [www.certifiedhacker.com](http://www.certifiedhacker.com) I found IP: 162.241.216.11. But going reverse lookup with the IP I found box5331.bluehost.com instead of [www.certifiedhacker.com](http://www.certifiedhacker.com)

Why this does happen?

Comment: There is no guarantee that reverse DNS round-trips to the same address, and in fact impossible if the IP address corresponds to more than one DNS label. In very short, the explanation is that the owner of the zone `241.162.in-addr.arpa.` put that information there. You'll have to find out who they are and ask them if you need more details than that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange apple dns answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121540/strange-apple-dns-answers)

Comment: This doesn't look like a security question but a DNS basics question. There isn't a 1:1 relationship between IPs and domains.

Answer (score 2):

It basically happens because the forward (name to IP) tree and the reverse (IP to name) tree are separate, and the same entity might not be controlling both.

When you are the owner of one node in the forward tree, you are free to map names to any IP address, including those you don't control. It happens anyway more and more with big webhosting companies, CDNs, etc.

In the same way, when you are the owner of one one in the reverse tree, you are free to map IP addresses to any names, including those you don't control and even some that do not exist/do not resolve anymore.

And even if everything would be in sync at a given time, names and IP addresses change, and hence things would start to become out of sync.

Anyway, the reverse tree is not really needed a lot today, except around email handling for servers. IP addresses used for webhosting for example do not need any `PTR` record to work. Do note however that some tool try to derive property from any `PTR` record on an IP for example to detect some patterns in the name to define if the IP is from an ISP or a cloud computing company, etc.

In short, there is no guarantee that you have a full round-trip: `name -> IP -> name` or as used in the past `IP -> name -> IP` to control source IP attempting to connect some services and restrict based on that.

PS: do attempt to not stay in last century legacy internet. Remember that nowadays IPv6 should be the norm, not IPv4. All the above remains the same, there is just another separate reverse tree for IPv6 :-)